# Release webcam when disconnected from a Flex project

Tags: xml, apache-flex

i'm working on a flex project using my webcam. everything works very well but there is just one think i don't know how to do it: when i disconnect from my "Video-chat" window, the webcam still on and i can't disconnect it. Notes: when i finish Logging in, i call a function to init everything in my Vdeo-chat window:

```
`public function initVars() : void
    {
        urlBox_publish.text = "rtmp:/live";
        streamBox_publish.text = "cameraFeed";
        urlBox_playbk.text = "rtmp:/live";
        streamBox_playbk.text = "cameraFeed";
        initCamera();
        return;
    }// end function`


  public function initCamera() : void
    {
        trace("In InitCamera");
        myCamera = Camera.getCamera();
        if (!myCamera)
        {
            trace("Error, No camera is installed");
            errorBox_publish.text = "Error, No camera is installed";
            errorBox_publish.visible = true;
            bPlayStop_publish.visible = false;
            publishBtn.visible = false;
            cameraDetectTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, initCamera);
            cameraDetectTimer.start();
            return;
        }
        myCamera.setMode(314, 214, 12);
        localVideo.attachCamera(myCamera);
        errorBox_publish.visible = false;
        bPlayStop_publish.visible = true;
        publishBtn.visible = true;
        return;
    }// end function
```

Comment: Once you're done with your camera, release all eventhandlers and set `myCamera` to `null`. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To release the used webcam simple do `video.attachCamera(null)`.

I would also follow wat dirkgently said here above, it's always positive to have some code cleanup on objects that are disposed.